# Converting strings into a readable R text

Tags: r

I have some input texts that looks as such:

```
names <- c(" ", " ")
users <- c("user1", "user2")

df <- cbind(names, users) %>% as.data.frame()
```

I am trying to convert it into a readable text within R because right now, it doesn't appear to be identifying it as such. For example if I tried to convert them into lower case only:

```
df$lowername <- tolower(df$names)
```

It would just spit back the same thing.

Is there any way I can convert text strings like these into a readable text format in R so I can then manipulate/clean the text like any other string?

So that names would become "Enyis Suaza" and "Victoria Langel" ?

Comment: I fear that you need manual tables for mapping the unicode characters. For `R`, I've found the following: https://github.com/rich-iannone/unidecoder However, it works only with a small subset for some languages and not for your usecase. There is a [perl tool](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Unidecode) that does this and that was [ported to python](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option

```
library(Unicode)
library(stringr)
unname(str_to_title(sapply(df$names, \(x) {
   x <- u_char_name(as.u_char(utf8ToInt(x)))
   paste(ifelse(x != "SPACE", substring(x, nchar(x)), " "), collapse = "")
 })))
```

-output

```
[1] "Enyis Suaza"     "Victoria Langel"
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but when I try to run it I'm met with the following:

 Error in as.u_char(utf8ToInt(x)) : could not find function "as.u_char"

Comment: @wizkids121 I loaded the `Unicode` package `library(Unicode)`

Comment: Ah got it, just had to do: Unicode::as.uchar

Comment: @wizkids121 if you haven't loaded the package, yes, otherwise it is not a internal function

Answer (score 2):

An imperfect approach is to identify the ASCII code that represents the letter, then figure out the difference between that ASCII code and the code that represents the "normal" text of that letter. Since there are multiple non-standard type here, unfortunately (to my knowledge) it has to be done for each type.

```
utf8ToInt("") - utf8ToInt("E")
# [1] 127279

utf8ToInt("") - utf8ToInt("V")
# [1] 119743
```

Since this difference is the same across all letters, you can then apply this difference using both `utf8ToInt` and `intToUtf8` to convert:

```
# using `names` instead of `names` since `names` is a function 
nnames <- c(" ", " ")

# Use Vectorize() to vectorize the utf8ToInt
vec.utf8ToInt <- Vectorize(utf8ToInt)

# the `ifelse` accounts for the normal space (" ") between the names
enyis_ASCII <- ifelse(vec.utf8ToInt(nnames)[[1]] - 127279 < 0, 
                      32, vec.utf8ToInt(nnames)[[1]] - 127279)
enyis_char <- intToUtf8(enyis_ASCII)
enyis_char
# [1] "ENYIS SUAZA"

victoria_ASCII <- ifelse(vec.utf8ToInt(nnames)[[2]] - 119743 < 0, 
                         32, vec.utf8ToInt(nnames)[[2]] - 119743)
victoria_char <- intToUtf8(victoria_ASCII)
victoria_char
# [1] "VICTORIA LANGEL"
```

You can make this a little cleaner by wrapping in a function and preserving the formatting type as the name of the vector, but still specific to the formatting type:

```
fixchars <- Vectorize(function(x){
  ints <- vec.utf8ToInt(x)
  if(all((ints[!(ints == 32)] - 127279) %in% 65:90)){
    ints[!(ints == 32)] <- ints[!(ints == 32)] - 127279
  }
  if(all((ints[!(ints == 32)] - 119743) %in% 65:90)){
    ints[!(ints == 32)] <- ints[!(ints == 32)] - 119743
  }
  intToUtf8(ints)
})

fixchars(nnames)
#        
# "ENYIS SUAZA" "VICTORIA LANGEL"
```

I am hoping a smarter coder than me can improve this answer by making it scalable. Great question - good luck!